# How to retain the content of form when page reloads?

Tags: php, session, upload

I have a **[php](/questions/tagged/php)** form where user enters data and in between uploads multiple documents.

Every time user selects a file and clicks on `upload` prior to pressing the `submit` button is the following code:

```php
if ( isset($_POST['Upload'] ) ) {
    //upload code is here
}
```

The problem is that the page reloads everytime the user clicks on `upload` and all the data entered in the textbox is wiped off.

It is required that the data already entered into the form be there after the file is uploaded and the page reloads.

Should I use:

```php
isset($_POST['Upload'] )
```

or should I use a session variable to store the content of the textbox?

Comment: I prefer for this situation ie you can use ajax file upload in this case just google it you can find ajax file uploading in php or please have look at this. https://www.sanwebe.com/2012/06/ajax-file-upload-with-php-and-jquery this may help you.

Comment: PUT value in $_SESSION and also use http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php